# How can I re-start code from the point that CSV write is completed?

Tags: python, csv, exception, web-crawler

I made a web crawler for this page (http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/cyber/CyberCar.php?gubun=I) to collect the stock list of each page and write information(e.g. photo url, title, description, date, price, etc.) in CSV.

Sometimes "exceptions" are randomly popped up while collecting the lists. When I re-start the entire code, sometimes the exception does not appear. I used "try and except" function inside of while loop to avoid the exception like below, but when the exception appears, the run continues in the while loop and can't get out of it.

```
while True:
    try:
        self.driver.execute_script(option2[1])
    except (StaleElementReferenceException, NoSuchElementException):
        sleep(1)
        print("Exception Found")
        continue
    break
```

What I would like to do is to re-start the entire code from the last list written in CSV when the exception begins. My code is pretty long, so it is hard to describe exactly which part to be started. But, what I am wondering is if there is any specific command or logic to get the information of that last list in CSV and re-start the code from that point when the exception appears.I know my description is poor but can you guys give me any advice or something?

Comment: "Thus, I would like to re-start the entire code from the list that exception begins" please explain this line.

Comment: I rephrase my sentence, but I know it is still not clear. This is my best description.

Comment: I understood the problem but before answering I want to clear my last doubt. What is "option2[1]"? what is the type of option2.

Comment: I collect the item information from each drop down menu. option2 is the last column of the first row drop-down menu in the page. The first index (option2[0]) is the text information of the item in the drop-down menu and the second index (option2[1]) is the value information which I use to select the item.

Comment: If you wrapped smaller parts of your code in try/except, it would be easier to restart a small part. I suspect you'd have to add exception handling inside `.execute_script`, and restart smaller parsing actions there.

Answer (score 0):

Well your question is not clear to me yet.

```
import csv
with open(filename) as f:
    last_record = list(csv.reader(f))[-1]
```

You can use the above code to get the last record written in the csv file and use it accordingly. Please inform if its not the answer you wanted.